# Possibilities for improving performance of this section of code

Tags: c, performance, optimization

I have some C code -

```
#define BYTE uint8_t

typedef __uint128_t uint128_t;
typedef __int128_t int128_t;

// Buffer for sample
int128_t samp_buf = 0;

// A struct Sample represents the instantaneous sound data for one channel.
typedef struct {
    // LSB-...-MSB representation of instantaneous amplitude.
    BYTE byte[meta.bytes_per_sample];
} Sample;

// A struct block represents the instantaneous sound data for all channels.
typedef struct {
    // 1 sample for each channel.
    Sample sample[meta.samples_per_block];
} Block;
```

This is the problematic part -

```
for (size_t byte_i = 0; byte_i < bytes_per_sample; byte_i++) {
    // Performance bottleneck
    samp_buf = samp_buf | blocks[block_i].sample[sample_i].byte[byte_i] << (8 * (byte_i));
}
```

Which basically loads bytes stored in `sample_i`'th sample of `block_i`'th block one-by-one.

`perf` tells me that this is the hottest section of the code.

I have tried to copy all the bytes in one go using memcpy but that provides no real speed-up (bottleneck simply moves to
`libc.so`)

Is there any way to speed this up?

Thank You,

Comment: What are typical values for `bytes_per_sample`? Given that using `memcpy` does not result in any performance gains, the first rule of data copying seems to apply here: Don't copy! In high-performance software, data transfer without concurrent data processing is to be avoided (zero-copy interfaces etc). Could you pass around pointers to relevant data that other parts of the code can use  to access the data *at the original location*?

Comment: How many bytes per sample?  You might want to look into using something like GCC's [`__builtin_ia32_por128()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/x86-Built-in-Functions.html) and maybe vectorize the calculation.  Or you could add an appropriately-sized `uintN_t` if one of those matches as part of a `union` with your `byte` field and maybe skip the bitwise-or loop entirely.

Comment: And lose the non-standard `BYTE` `typedef` and use standard and portable `uint8_t`.

Comment: Can you replace the `BYTE byte[meta.bytes_per_sample];` field with `uint128_t bytes;` and then just do `samp_buf = sblocks[block_i].sample[sample_i].bytes;` with no loop? Using a variable number of bytes (instead of a fixed size with a variable amount of unused/padding), possibly with "unfortunate alignment"; creates more complications for the CPU.